# Change URL while remain Full Screen with Meteor + iron-router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, fullscreen, iron-router, html5-history

Given a Meteor application using Iron Router, on page A I've gone full screen. Then I surf to page B and I want to remain in full screen.

With `Router.go('pageB');` this wouldn't work as the browser changes the URL.

However, given a recent [change in Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138324), the following should be possible:

1. Render the state and full route of pageB on the client (Meteor FTW)
2. `history.push({},'Page B', '/pageB');`

That's the theory. Is this feasible? And if so, how?

Comment: I have a repo on which I tried to reproduce this, and could not. I'm on a Mac, on Chrome Version ( 44.0.2403.157), the repo is the one here: https://github.com/okgrow/router-autoscroll/tree/master/examples/iron-router-example, and I went full screen using Shift-Cmd-F. It stayed full screen as I changed URLs. Perhaps you could elaborate your repro notes ?

Comment: The issue is with entering full-screen through `Element.requestFullscreen()` as opposed to a keyboard shortcut. You are right: the shortcut remains full screen during url change, however, the other does not.